# How to solve the Laplace equation in a ring. polar coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Tell me please to solve the Laplace equation for the ring? Recorded the equation in polar coordinates, set the domain, Dirichlet boundary conditions, but outputs...

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
  { ρ^2 D[ u[ρ, ϕ], ρ, ρ] + ρ D[ u[ρ, ϕ], ρ] +  D[u[ρ, ϕ], ϕ, ϕ] == 0
  , DirichletCondition[u[ρ, ϕ] == 1000., ρ == .5 && 0 <= ϕ <= 2 π]
  , DirichletCondition[ u[ρ, ϕ] == 0., ρ == 10 && 0 <= ϕ <= 2 π]
  }
, u, {ρ, 0.5, 10}, {ϕ, 0, 2π}  
 ]

DensityPlot[sol[ρ, ϕ], {ρ, 0.5, 10}, {ϕ, 0, 2π }
, Mesh -> All
, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

Output :

[image]

Note that the mesh above is not the mesh used by `NDSolveValue`. It is a mesh created by `DensityPlot`. The mesh used by `NDSolveValue` is :

```
DensityPlot[sol[\[Rho], \[Phi]], {\[Rho],\[Phi]} \[Element] sol["ElementMesh"]
, Mesh -> All
, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

The question is : how to transform the coordinates of the mesh(es) so that we retrieve the correct geometry of the domain : a ring ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68969/discussion-on-question-by-alex-how-to-solve-the-laplace-equation-in-a-ring-pola).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution to get the right geometry :

**Mesh from DensityPlot**

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
  { \[Rho]^2 D[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Rho], \[Rho]] + \[Rho] D[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Rho]] +  D[u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Phi], \[Phi]] == 0
  , DirichletCondition[u[\[Rho], \[Phi]] == 1000., \[Rho] == .5 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]]
  , DirichletCondition[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]] == 0., \[Rho] == 10 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]]
  }
, u, {\[Rho], 0.5, 10}, {\[Phi], 0, 2\[Pi]}  
 ];

gr00=DensityPlot[sol[\[Rho], \[Phi]], {\[Rho], 0.5, 10}, {\[Phi], 0, 2\[Pi] }
, Mesh -> All
, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
];  

Show[gr00 /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :>  
                  GraphicsComplex[(#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]],Sin[#[[2]]]})& /@ array1, rest],
                  PlotRange -> 10 {{-1,1},{-1,1}}
                  ]
```

[image]

**Mesh from NDSolveValue**

**EDIT**

**THERE WAS A ERROR IN MY ANSWER JUST AFTER THIS EDIT**

The real mesh used by `NDSolve[...]` is given by :

```
Show[sol["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"] /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :>  
                  GraphicsComplex[(#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]],Sin[#[[2]]]})& /@ array1, rest],
                  PlotRange -> 10 {{-1,1},{-1,1}}
                  ]
```

[image]

**END EDIT**

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
  { \[Rho]^2 D[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Rho], \[Rho]] + \[Rho] D[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Rho]] +  D[u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Phi], \[Phi]] == 0
  , DirichletCondition[u[\[Rho], \[Phi]] == 1000., \[Rho] == .5 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]]
  , DirichletCondition[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]] == 0., \[Rho] == 10 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]]
  }
, u, {\[Rho], 0.5, 10}, {\[Phi], 0, 2\[Pi]}  
 ];

gr01=DensityPlot[sol[\[Rho], \[Phi]], {\[Rho],\[Phi]} \[Element] sol["ElementMesh"]
, Mesh -> All
, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
];

Show[gr01 /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :>  
                  GraphicsComplex[(#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]],Sin[#[[2]]]})& /@ array1, rest],
                  PlotRange -> 10 {{-1,1},{-1,1}}
                  ]
```

[image]

**WARNING**

The question is restricted to the particular case where the solution doesn't depend of Phi. All derivative related to phi are 0.

Let see what's happening if the diffusion of heat is not radial, for example suppose that the heating is only done in the upper-right part of the inner boundary. Here is the code  :

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
  { \[Rho]^2 D[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Rho], \[Rho]] + \[Rho] D[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Rho]] +  D[u[\[Rho], \[Phi]], \[Phi], \[Phi]] == 0
  , DirichletCondition[u[\[Rho], \[Phi]] == If[0 <\[Phi]< Pi/2,1000.,200.], \[Rho] == 2 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]]
  , DirichletCondition[ u[\[Rho], \[Phi]] == 0, \[Rho] == 10 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]]
  }
, u, {\[Rho], 2, 10}, {\[Phi], 0, 2\[Pi]}  
 ];

gr02=DensityPlot[sol[\[Rho], \[Phi]], {\[Rho], 2, 10}, {\[Phi], 0, 2\[Pi] }
, Mesh -> All
, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
,PlotRange -> All
];    

Show[gr02 /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :>  
                  GraphicsComplex[(#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]],Sin[#[[2]]]})& /@ array1, rest],
                  PlotRange -> 10 {{-1,1},{-1,1}}
                  ]
```

[image]

The heat doesn't diffuse through the line phi=0. This is because the domain has 4 boundaries : R=0.5 , R=10 , but also phi=0 , phi=2 Pi. The boundary conditions are not specified on the boundaries  phi=0 , phi=2 Pi. In this case, `NDSolve` takes the default boudary condition which is Neumann=0 (ie Heat flux=0).<strike>The problem can be solved on the most recent versions of mathematica, where periodic Neumann conditions are introduced.</strike> *(stroken because probably false, not sure)*
**Edit**
Finally, the problem of the undesirable boundary at phi=0 is solved [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174514/5467)

Comment: Maybe it's possible to contruct a mesh with only 2 boundaries (the two circles) . I have not tried. Or maybe "sewing" 2 boundaries of a 4 boundaries domain ?

Comment: maybe this brings clarity into the picture, I want to calculate this kind of configuration: [link](https://yadi.sk/i/p6NnD2Jk3PqZiu) @ander

Comment: Note : The equations of heat are exactly the same than the equations of potential. Just replace °C by Volts.

Comment: seconde case 2) there is "nothing" outside
well, I'll look at this virtual charge method

Answer (score 2):

In this configuration, there is no problem with stitching the borders

```
h = ImplicitRegion[0.25 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 100, {x, y}];


sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,    

DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 10.,x^2 + y^2 == 0.25 &&  N[ArcTan[x, y] <= 0]],   

DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., x^2 + y^2 == 100 && N[ArcTan[x, y] >=  0]]},u, {x, y} ∈ h]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: great answer!but why you use N[ArcTan[x, y] <= 0] and N[ArcTan[x, y] >= 0] ,and what about don't use it?

Comment: And theresult is not symmetrical.

Comment: I wanted to solve the problem of a cylindrical "capacitor" which has a cut in the wall.

Therefore, it is understandable that the result will not be symmetrical @dcydhb

Comment: and what about my first question?and why your answer is different from the answer1 ,which is right