# Solve Laplace equation in Cylindrical - Polar Coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, numerical-value

Hey *mathematica stackexchange*!! I've got a (possibly stupid) problem. I've tried many things to no avail, and I've read every post I've found on Laplace's equation.

**Background:**
I'm trying to find the capacitance per unit length of the following system (where the image is a perpendicular view of an infinite cylinder):
[image: Problem image.]

My approach is to first find the potential using

$$\nabla^2_{polar}V=\frac{V^{(0,2)}(\rho ,\phi )}{\rho^2}+\frac{V^{(1,0)}(\rho ,\phi)}{\rho }+V^{(2,0)}(\rho ,\phi )=0$$

Then, I would take the (negative) gradient and find $\vec{E}$ and, using that $\sigma = \varepsilon_{0}*(\vec{E} \cdot \hat{n})$, I'd get $\sigma$ in the upper left surface and integrate it to get $Q$ (per unit length). With that, $C=\frac{Q}{\Delta V}$.

The answer is supposed to be $\frac{\varepsilon_0}{\pi}*Log[2]\sim1.9$  $pF/m$ (given in the article from where my professor adapted the problem).

**Mathematica implementation:**

```
R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12;
regionCyl = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= r <= R && 0 <= p <= 2 Pi, {r, p}]; 

laplacianCil = Laplacian[V[r, p], {r, p}, "Polar"];
boundaryConditionCil = {DirichletCondition[
    V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 0 <= p <= Pi/2], 
   DirichletCondition[
    V[r, p] == 
     V1, r == R && Pi <= p <= 3/2 Pi]};

solCyl = NDSolveValue[{laplacianCil == 0, boundaryConditionCil}, 
  V, {r, 1*^-12, R}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

electricFieldCyl = -Grad[solCyl[r, p], {r, p}, 
    "Polar"];
sigmaCyl = (Dot[
     electricFieldCyl, -{1, 0}] /. {r -> 
      R})*e0;
Q0Cyl = NIntegrate[sigmaCyl, {p, 0, Pi/2}];
capacitanceCyl = Abs[Q0Cyl]/Abs[V0 - V1]
```

With this, I get $C = 5.644674742129655*10^{-12}$.

*The questions:*

1. How should I go about solving this problem? Is my implementation correct? I mean, are boundary conditions and the equation correctly passed to NDSolveValue? (ignoring physics).
2. Calculation time is extremely fast (less than 2 secconds to run all the code + some plots). So much so that I think the NDSolveValue is not correctly solving my problem. How can I increase resolution?

I tried to add another Boundary Condition for $V[\infty,\phi]=0, 0 < \phi <2 \pi$ with

```
DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == 0, r == 1*^6*R && 0 <= p <= 2*Pi];
```

However, NDSolve fails to solve the equation.

(I believe I'm missing $\sigma$ on the outer side of the cylinder. I'm not sure how to evaluate this. This part of the problem is not for this forum so I tried to limit my question to Mathematica. But, by all means, correct my physics if they're wrong)

Comment: One problem I see is that your resultant potential is not periodic in `p`.  If you plot solCyl, you will see that the values at `p = 2 Pi` are not the same as at `p = 0`, but then your bc's are not requiring that.  MMa does seem to be honoring the bc's you have specified, however.  Your `V` at your minimum `r` should be pretty constant with `p`, but is not, but haven't specified that bc either.  As an aside, the capacitance should only depend on the geometry of the system and not the applied potentials, so if C is all you want, you could try more symmetric values as a check.

Comment: @BillWatts "The values at p=2 Pi are not the same as at p=0" : see my Warning at the end of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160241/5467)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer has to be single valued in polar angle from a physics point of view.  MMa doesn't care though if not specified.

Comment: @andre: I've edited my post with the exact (analytic) result that I was given. I'll be waiting for more info on your progress!! Thanks!

Comment: @BillWatts I tried adding a DirichletCondition for `V[R, 2Pi] ==V0`, but it didn't change my answer. How would you solve the problem if you had total freedom to do so? BTW, I'm trying to solve the problem with `V1=-1; V0=1` for that same reason. But Mma converges on the same answer, no matter what potentials I select (which is what should happen, I believe).

Comment: I will think about it some more.  I haven't tried, but shifting your pieces of the cylinder to 0 to Pi/4, 3 Pi/4 to 5 Pi/4 and 7 Pi/4 to 2 Pi will make it symmetric about the x axis and assure that the Potential at 0 is the same as at 2 Pi.  I haven't looked at everything in detail, but it is an interesting problem worth looking at some more when I have time.

Comment: I  have doubt about the theorical value 1.9 pF/m, because if one replaces the arc of circle by straigtht lines (with same extremities) and doesn't care of fringing, then one have : e0 R Sqrt[2]/(R Sqrt[2]) = e0 = 8.85 pF/m. In reality the fringing will increase this value. Where does your formula comes from ?. (Note that this doubt doesn't mean that my value (5.8pF) is right).

Comment: @BillWatts Do you mean shifting the plaques so that they span from -45° to 45° and 135° to 225°? If so, I tried it and the answer doesn't change (which is physically expected).

Comment: @andre Yes, I have my doubts too. The only issue I see with my method is that I'm not considering the charge on the outside of the plaque. I'm not sure how to do so, as I cannot assume $V(\infty)=0$ cause the system is itself infinite. Thus, I have no idea how to solve the equation for the region outside.

The article is [this](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.19203). I'll try to see if my professor let's me read it (he has a copy). I'll update here when I have news. Thanks for the interest!!

Comment: Using `boundaryConditionCil = {DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V0, 
   r == R && 0 <= p <= Pi/4], 
  DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V1, r == R && 3 Pi/4 <= p <= 5 Pi/4], 
  DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 7 Pi/4 <= p <= 2 Pi]}`,  I get symmetric potential from 0 to 2 Pi.  The electric field is symmetric also, but there is an unexplained discontinuity in slope in the electric field at `p = 0.616` and other places.  The electric field is very choppy which may be throwing off the numerics.

Comment: @BillWatts Is the electric field choppy because `NDSolveValue` is returning a $V$ that hasn't a high enough resolution?? I tried adding `MaxStepSize -> 1*^-6` to my code, but the answer didn't change. As an aside, why is the answer changing with the rotation of my system?

Comment: Forcing MMa to make the potential single valued in `p` by shifting the rotation is actually changing the boundary conditions of the problem with the corresponding change in all the results.  I also had no luck in tightening the grid.  Might have to try analytic solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is better to use Cartesian coordinates because one does not have to deal with the periodicity in p. To have control on the meshing of the the region, we tell Mathematica explicitly to discretize it. `PrecisionGoal -> 6` controls the meshing at the boundary. But this does not always work. Alternatively, one can use `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001` or a `MeshRefinementFunction` as done in the calculation below. The MeshRegion (`FullForm[regionCyl]`) is then passed directly to `NDSolveValue`. user21 pointed out that one may get a higher quality solution when using `ElementMesh` because it uses second-order mesh elements ([reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)). To specify the angle in the boundary conditions using {x,y}-coordinates you need `ArcTan` with two arguments ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)). `ArcTan[y/x]` would only cover an interval from -Pi/2 to Pi/2. The electrostatic potential (`sol`) as a function of x and y is calculated by `NDSolveValue`. The electric field is the negative gradient of the electrostatic potential. The plots below visualize the electric field lines together with the potential. The charge in a region of interest is given by the scalar product of its normal vectors and the electric field (`sigmaCyl`) integrated along the (closed) boundary of the region. This flux normal to the boundary (`sigmaCyl`) is plotted below from -2 Pi to 2 Pi. Integration of the flux is carried out for one of the plates (from 0 to p0). The electrical field exactly on the boundary is not completely covered by the mesh due to numerical inaccuracies. That is why I use the field close to the boundary at 0.999 R. The capacitance (`capacitanceCyl`) of the structure is given by its charge per voltage.

```
Clear[sigmaCyl]
R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12; p0 = Pi/2;
regionCyl = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= R, {x, y}], PrecisionGoal -> 6]
laplacian = Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}];
boundaryCondition = {
  DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V0, 0 < ArcTan[x, y] < p0],
  DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V1, -Pi < ArcTan[x, y] < -Pi + p0]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{laplacian == 0, boundaryCondition}, V, {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl];
electricField[x_, y_] = -Grad[sol[x, y], {x, y}];
Row[{Show[
   DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> Medium],
   StreamPlot[electricField[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, StreamStyle -> Black]],
  Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", BoxRatios -> {1,1,1}, ImageSize -> Medium]}]
sigmaCyl[p_] = electricField[0.999 R Cos[p], 0.999 R Sin[p]].{Cos[p], Sin[p]}*e0;
Plot[sigmaCyl[p], {p, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
Q0Cyl = NIntegrate[sigmaCyl[p], {p, 0, p0}, AccuracyGoal -> 5];
capacitanceCyl = Abs[Q0Cyl]/Abs[V0 - V1]
```

[image]
[image]

**Edit:** As pointed out by Peanut14, to get a physically meaningful capacitance one has to consider the electric field outside of the cylinder, too. Here, a `MeshRefinementFunction` is used to get smaller mesh elements for r < 3. The function gets two parameters from `DiscretizeRegion`. The first one is a list of the coordinates of the 3 edges of each element. The second one is its area. `DiscretizeRegion` expects a Boolean result telling it whether it should refine the element or not. For reasons of speed this function is compiled. You may also pass a not compiled function. Then `DiscretizeRegion` will compile it for you. But the problem is that it does not throw an error message if it fails (as of version 11.3). Instead it just ignores the refinement function.

```
Clear[sigmaCyl]
R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12; p0 = Pi/2;
ra = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 10, {x, y}]];
rb = RegionUnion[
   DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[r {Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {{r, 1, 1.1}, {p, 0, p0}}]], 
   DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[r {Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {{r, 1, 1.1}, {p, -Pi, -Pi + p0}}]]];
mrf = Compile[{{vertices, _Real, 2}, {area, _Real, 0}}, If[area > 10^-2 && Norm[Mean[vertices]] < 3, True, False]];
regionCyl = DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[ra, rb], MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf]
laplacian = Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}];
boundaryCondition = {
   DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V0, 0 <= ArcTan[x, y] <= p0 && Norm[{x, y}] < 1.5],
   DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V1, -Pi <= ArcTan[x, y] <= -Pi + p0 && Norm[{x, y}] < 1.5]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{laplacian == 0, boundaryCondition}, V, {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl];
electricField[x_, y_] = -Grad[sol[x, y], {x, y}];
s[t_] = {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]} + RotationMatrix[Pi/4].{Cos[t], 1.5 Sin[t]};
n[t_] = FrenetSerretSystem[s[t], t][[2, 2]](*normals to s[t]*);
Row[{Show[
   DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> Medium], 
   StreamPlot[electricField[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, StreamStyle -> Black],
   ParametricPlot[s[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]],
  Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] RegionIntersection[regionCyl, DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]]], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", BoxRatios -> {1,1,1}, ImageSize -> Medium]}]
sigmaCyl[t_] = n[t].electricField @@ s[t]*e0;
Plot[sigmaCyl[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
Q0Cyl = NIntegrate[sigmaCyl[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 5];
capacitanceCyl = Abs[Q0Cyl]/Abs[V0 - V1]
```

[image]
[image]

Now, that is the capacitance.

**Edit:** The situation your professor is referring to is slightly different. A closed cylinder is divided in 4 segments by two perpendicular planes. One is along the symmetry axis the other with variable position (adjustable by p0). The upper-right segment is on the potential V0. The other 3 segments are on ground. Now, the charge on the lower-left segment is always the same for a given voltage independent of the position of the second plane. The so-called cross-capacitance between the lower-left and the upper-right segment is ε0/π∗Log[2]. This holds even for arbitrarily shaped cross-sections as long as they are mirror symmetric. Such a configuration is believed to result in a very stable capacitor. The original paper of Thompson and Lampard is not freely accessible but [here](https://oalibrary.org/papers2/2d4ca965-7802-4110-906e-a0de5044497a/) is an open access paper that explains a bit of the context.

```
Clear[sigmaCyl]
R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12; p0 = 0.5 Pi /2;
regionCyl = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= R, {x, y}], PrecisionGoal -> 6];
laplacian = Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}];
boundaryCondition = {DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V0, 0 < ArcTan[x, y] < p0], DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V1, True]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{laplacian == 0, boundaryCondition}, V, {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl];
electricField[x_, y_] = -Grad[sol[x, y], {x, y}];
Row[{Show[
   DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All], 
   StreamPlot[electricField[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, StreamStyle -> Black],
   Graphics[{Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, p0}], Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {-Pi, -p0}], Dashed, Line[{{Cos[p0], -1}, {Cos[p0], 1}}], Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]}]],
  Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All]}]
sigmaCyl[p_] = electricField[0.9999 R Cos[p], 0.9999 R Sin[p]].{Cos[p], Sin[p]}*e0;
Plot[sigmaCyl[p], {p, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
Q0Cyl = NIntegrate[sigmaCyl[p], {p, -Pi, -p0}, AccuracyGoal -> 5];
capacitanceCyl = Abs[Q0Cyl]/Abs[V0 - V1]
```

[image]

Note that the vertical line does not have to be in the middle. The cross-capacitance is always the same. In general, the electric field between the lower-left and the upper-right segment outside of the cylinder has to be considered, too. But it is smaller due to the other segments. In practical situations the segmented cylinder is shielded with a non-segmented cylinder around it that is on ground potential.

Comment: @andre ah, yes. The value I got is close to the one that you calculated. That was for a plate capacitor with plates of length R Sqrt[2] and distance R Sqrt[2], right? That seems to make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yesterday I went to his office, but he was not there. I'll have to wait until Monday to talk this through with him. I too suspect of the "correct" answer, but was unsure about my &5.6 pF/m& answer as well. Question: by evaluating `sigmaCyl` at 0.999*R, are you considering a plaque of thickness 0.001? If so, wouldn't I need to also solve for the $\sigma$ on the outer face of the plaque?

Comment: BTW, I'm using MMa 10 and I get this error  `Range specification {x,y}\[Element]regionCyl is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}` (from Stream plot). I don't really need a solution for that (I can work around it). Just thought I'd let you know :) .

Comment: @Peanut14 You are welcome! The electrical field exactly on the boundary is not completely covered by the mesh due to numerical inaccuracies. That is why I used  0.999 R. The outer face is actually not existent in the model because the potential is only calculated within the region defined by regionCyl.

Comment: @MatthiasBernien I understand the model doesn't cover that face. But, should it? I mean, this is now phyisics. But, how would I extend $V$ to cover all of space (or at least the interior of the cylinder and a region around it). Which version of MMa are you using?

Comment: @Peanut14 If the cylinder is open, yes it should. `ra = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 2, {x, y}]]; rb = RegionUnion[DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[r {Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {{r, 1, 1.1}, {p, 0, Pi/2}}]], DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[ r {Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {{r, 1, 1.1}, {p, -Pi, -Pi + Pi/2}}]]]; regionCyl = DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[ra, rb], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]; boundaryCondition = {DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V0, 0 <= ArcTan[x, y] <= p0 && Norm[{x, y}] < 1.5], DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == V1, -Pi <= ArcTan[x, y] <= -Pi + p0 && Norm[{x, y}] < 1.5]};`

Comment: Cartesian coordinates are also a good thing for other reasons (than the artificial boudary phi=0 you mention) : 1) the mesh is regular (in polar coordinates it is more dense at the origin 2) there's no PolarRegionPlot in Mathematica. These two problems can be seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160241/5467). Personnaly, every time I used polar coordinates with NDSolve and fem (3 times in facts), I came to the conclusion that is was a bad choice.

Comment: I think that in your code : `p0 = 0.5 Pi /2`should be `p0 = 0.5 Pi`, and consequently the figures should be corrected. Or it is deliberate ?

Comment: ... deliberate to illustrate your text : "This holds even for arbitrarily shaped cross-sections as long as they have a symmetry axis".

Comment: @andre yes, this was intended. I wanted to highlight that the result is the same independent of the position of the second plane.

Comment: @MatthiasBernien Your answer is terrific! You went into a lot of detail and solved the problem completely. I learned quiate a lot about MMa. I'll wait unitl I speak with my professor to show him all of this and update the page with a comment. I'll probably mark yours as the answer, I just want him to see it first.

Comment: @Peanut14 It was fun doing it! I am curious if it is correct :)

Comment: @Peanut14, for a better quality solution you could use `ToElementMesh` in stead of `DiscretizeRegion`.

Comment: @user21 Can you elaborate in which respect the quality of the solution is better?

Comment: @MatthiasBernien, see [this tutorials](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Comment: Just today I saw my professor to give him the link to these answers. I'll update with his response, so we'll know for sure which problem we're trying to solve.

Comment: @MatthiasBernien Thanks for your patience! I have a couple questions: **1)** So, is the problem I posted (with 2 plaques and the rest as "free space" with potential not imposed as V1) different from the one that gives 1.9 pF/m? As I gather from your code, you impose potential as V1 everywhere that is not the plaque in the first quadrant (so 0 in the remaining 3 plaques). **2)** From the code that you made considering E outside the system: I cannot understand what Norm[x,y] < 1.5 means. Would you mind adding an outline of what the code does? I'm immensely grateful for your help!!!

Comment: @Peanut14 1) Yes, to have a constant value you need to fix the potential on the cylinder. I only understood this by reading the papers. Actually, the library of your university should provide you with access to these journals, too. Usually, you can access the articles from the publishers website if you use the intranet of your university.

Comment: @Peanut14 2) `Norm[{x,y}]<1.5` tells Mathematica that the condition is only for the boundaries in the center and not for the one at r=10. Mathematica itself knows that boundary conditions are always on the boundary, so it is enough to specify a region. I will add an outline. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a analysis of all the problems related to Mathematica in your question.

Briefly summarized, These are 3 problems :

- the lack of build-in tools to visualize the potential and vector field in polar coordinates.
- boundary problems : Whatever is the real geometry you are interested (not clear in your question, especially you want to optain 1.9 pF/m), there are boundaries that are not expected (compared to your description of the geometry). This will become clear once we will have the tools to visualize the vector field
- There is also a difficulty due with the fact that Grad[potential] return a pair of Interpolation functions and not a unique interpolation function that returns a pair of values.

**Visualisation tools**

*You code (exactly) :*

```
R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12;
regionCyl = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= r <= R && 0 <= p <= 2 Pi, {r, p}]; 

laplacianCil = Laplacian[V[r, p], {r, p}, "Polar"];
boundaryConditionCil = {DirichletCondition[
    V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 0 <= p <= Pi/2], 
   DirichletCondition[
    V[r, p] == 
     V1, r == R && Pi <= p <= 3/2 Pi]};

solCyl = NDSolveValue[{laplacianCil == 0, boundaryConditionCil}, 
  V, {r, 1*^-12, R}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

electricFieldCyl = -Grad[solCyl[r, p], {r, p}, 
    "Polar"];
sigmaCyl = (Dot[
     electricFieldCyl, -{1, 0}] /. {r -> 
      R})*e0;
Q0Cyl = NIntegrate[sigmaCyl, {p, 0, Pi/2}];
capacitanceCyl = Abs[Q0Cyl]/Abs[V0 - V1]
```

*The potential :*

```
potentialSquareRepresentation=ContourPlot[solCyl[r, p], {r,p} \[Element] solCyl["ElementMesh"]
, ColorFunction -> "Temperature"
,Contours-> 20
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
];
potentialCylindricalRepresentation=Show[
potentialSquareRepresentation /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :>  
                  GraphicsComplex[(#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]],Sin[#[[2]]]})& /@ array1, rest],
PlotRange -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

*The field :*  , thanks to Matthias

```
electricField1[r_, p_] = -Grad[solCyl[r, p ], {r, p}, "Polar"];
electricField2[x_, y_] = TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", electricField1[r, p + Pi], {r, p } -> {x, y}] /. ArcTan[x_,y_]:> ArcTan[-x,-y];
fieldCylindricalRepresentation=StreamPlot[electricField2[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, StreamStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

*The mesh (the error mentionned in first User21's comment is corrected) :*

```
meshSquareRepresentation= solCyl["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"];
meshCylindricalRepresentation=Show[meshSquareRepresentation /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :>  
                  GraphicsComplex[(#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]],Sin[#[[2]]]})& /@ array1, rest],
                  PlotRange ->  {{-1,1},{-1,1}}
                  ]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

*a example of superposition :*

```
Show[potentialCylindricalRepresentation,fieldCylindricalRepresentation]
```

[image]

**Boundary problems**

As one can see on the graphics, the boundaries are :

- The two expected quarters of circle , the lower at 0 Volts, the upper at 1 Volt. That's fine.
- The boundary p=0 (ie angle=0). This boundary is a problem. It is not specified. In that case NDSolve takes the default boundary condition : Neuman=0, that is to say no field transverse to the boundary. This is clearly visible when one observes the field 
  lines.
- There are also the two quarters of circle complementary to the two quarters that have been specified. Mathematica has seen a boundary because it is the limit of the domain. Once again the default boundary condition Neumann=0 has been used (see the field lines)

... To be continued ...

**EDIT 01/01/2020**

I have found a solution to the unresolved problem mentionned just above : How to get rid of the boundary at p=0 (ie angle=0)?

The first idea that comes to mind is to apply a periodic boundary condition between the boundaries p=0 and p=2 Pi.

Here is the code :

```
R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12;
regionCyl = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= R && -Pi/4 <= p <= 2 Pi, {r, p}];

laplacianCil = Laplacian[V[r, p], {r, p}, "Polar"];
boundaryConditionCil = {
   DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 0 <= p <= Pi/2], 
   DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V1, r == R && Pi <= p <= 3/2 Pi]};

PeriodicBoundaryCondition00 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[V[r, p], p == 2 Pi, 
  Function[x, x + {0, -2 Pi}]]; (* this is new *)

solCyl = NDSolveValue[{
   laplacianCil == 0
   , boundaryConditionCil
   , PeriodicBoundaryCondition00 (* this is new *)
   }, V, {r, 1*^-12, R}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

potentialSquareRepresentation = 
  ContourPlot[solCyl[r, p], {r, p} \[Element] solCyl["ElementMesh"], 
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 20, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];
potentialCylindricalRepresentation = 
 Show[potentialSquareRepresentation /. {GraphicsComplex[array1_, 
      rest___] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[( {#[[1]] Cos[#[[2]]], #[[1]] Sin[#[[2]]]}) & /@ 
       array1, rest]}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

One sees that there is still a problem : The potential is continuous but the field  is discontinous.

That is not the solution to the physical problem.

Furthermore, I have done a arbitrary decision in the code just above : The documentation of `PeriodicNoudaryCondition` has a notion of source and target, and I have choosen which one is which one randomly. If the roles are interverted, it gives this :

```
 R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12;
regionCyl = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= R && -Pi/4 <= p <= 2 Pi, {r, p}];

laplacianCil = Laplacian[V[r, p], {r, p}, "Polar"];
boundaryConditionCil = {
   DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 0 <= p <= Pi/2], 
   DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V1, r == R && Pi <= p <= 3/2 Pi]};

PeriodicBoundaryCondition01 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[V[r, p], p == 0 && 0 < r < 1, 
  Function[x, x + {0, 2 Pi}]]; (* this is new *)

solCyl = NDSolveValue[{
   laplacianCil == 0
   , boundaryConditionCil
   , PeriodicBoundaryCondition01 (* this is new *)
   }, V, {r, 1*^-12, R}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

potentialSquareRepresentation = 
  ContourPlot[solCyl[r, p], {r, p} \[Element] solCyl["ElementMesh"], 
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 20, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];
potentialCylindricalRepresentation = 
 Show[potentialSquareRepresentation /. {GraphicsComplex[array1_, 
      rest___] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[( {#[[1]] Cos[#[[2]]], #[[1]] Sin[#[[2]]]}) & /@ 
       array1, rest]}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Once again, the field is not continuous.

*The solution*

First one must be aware that the source of a BoundaryCondition is not necessarily a boundary (!), and that in that case, one can use two Boundary conditions, each targeting a boundary : one targeting the boundary p=0, the other one targeting the boundary p=2 Pi. Since it is not possible assign a boundary as target and source at the same time, the sources can be anywhere except at these boundaries.

With these informations, it is now possible to impose continuity of potential and field together.

The trick (2) is to extend the angular domain to, say, [-Pi/4,2 Pi] (1),
it gives :

```
solCyl = NDSolveValue[{laplacianCil == 0, boundaryConditionCil}, 
   V, {r, 1*^-12, R}, {p, -Pi/4, 2 Pi}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

potentialSquareRepresentation = 
  ContourPlot[solCyl[r, p], {r, p} \[Element] solCyl["ElementMesh"], 
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 20, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];
potentialCylindricalRepresentation = 
 Show[potentialSquareRepresentation /. {GraphicsComplex[array1_, 
      rest___] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[( {#[[1]] Cos[#[[2]]], #[[1]] Sin[#[[2]]], \
#[[2]]}) & /@ array1, rest]
    , Graphics -> Graphics3D}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.1}, ViewPoint -> {3.14154, -0.356783, 1.2056}]
```

[image]

and then impose :

1) potential at target boundary p=2 Pi should be equal to potential at p=0 (source)
2) potential at target  boundary p=-Pi/4 should be equal to potential at p=2 Pi - Pi/4 (source)

Here is the code :

```
R = 1; V0 = 1; V1 = 0; e0 = 8.854187817*^-12;
regionCyl = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= R && -Pi/4 <= p <= 2 Pi, {r, p}];

laplacianCil = Laplacian[V[r, p], {r, p}, "Polar"];

boundaryConditionCil = {
   DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 0 <= p <= Pi/2], 
   DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V1, r == R && Pi <= p <= 3/2 Pi]};

solCyl = NDSolveValue[{
    laplacianCil == 0
    , PeriodicBoundaryCondition[V[r, p], p == 2 Pi, 
     Function[x, x + {0, -2 Pi}]]
    , PeriodicBoundaryCondition[V[r, p], p == -Pi/4 && 0 < r < 1, 
     Function[x, x + {0, 2 Pi}]]
    , boundaryConditionCil}, V, {r, 1*^-12, R}, {p, -Pi/4, 2 Pi}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];

potentialSquareRepresentation = 
  ContourPlot[solCyl[r, p], {r, p} \[Element] solCyl["ElementMesh"], 
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 20, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];
potentialCylindricalRepresentation = 
 Show[potentialSquareRepresentation /. {GraphicsComplex[array1_, 
        rest___] :> 
       GraphicsComplex[( {#[[1]] Cos[#[[2]]], #[[1]] Sin[#[[2]]], \
#[[2]]}) & /@ array1, rest]
      , Graphics -> Graphics3D}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.1}, 
    ViewPoint -> #] & /@ {{3.14154, -0.356783, 1.2056}, {0, 0, 
    10}, {0, 0, -10}}
```

The result (global view, top view, bottom view)

[image]

There is continuity of potential and field everywhere.
The problem is solved.

For fun, the vector field :

```
electricField1[r_, p_] = -Grad[solCyl[r, p], {r, p}, "Polar"];
electricField2[x_, y_] = 
  TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
    electricField1[r, p + Pi], {r, p} -> {x, y}] /. 
   ArcTan[x_, y_] :> ArcTan[-x, -y];
fieldCylindricalRepresentation = 
 StreamPlot[electricField2[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  StreamStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

(1) and extend the boundary r=1, here it's Neumann=0, so it's automatically done.
(2) which is valid, but to be convinced needs reflexion. By the way, I have not found this solution accidentally.

Comment: This is certainly not the mesh `NDSolve` used. Have a look at: `solCyl["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"]`

Comment: @user21 I have corrected the mesh. Thanks.

Comment: @andre If one rotates the boundary conditions the solutions looks a bit better: `boundaryConditionCil = {DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 0 < p < Pi/4],DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V0, r == R && 7/4 Pi < p < 2 Pi],DirichletCondition[V[r, p] == V1, r == R && 3/4 Pi < p < 5/4 Pi]}`

Comment: [link to a chatroom about the subject](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45037081#45037081)

Comment: It's great that you found an answer to this. Now I just need to understand it ;-) How did you come up with this?

Comment: @user21 Roughly : The domain decomposition method exposed by C. E. was a source of inspiration. Then I realized that if the 2 surfaces has the same boundaries conditions and the same topology, they have the same solution. And I discovered yesterday that there no need to iterate like in de domain decomposition method, because one can impose the two boundaries conditions thanks to the fact that the source are not necessarely boundaries. In parallel I could give some physical interpretations to the approach. (in 2D a region that self intersect may appear as pathologic, but not in 3D,

Comment: ...  if you imagine a spiral)

Comment: @andre314, git it - very clever. If you do not mind, I'd like to use this in the documentation.

Comment: @user21 No problem : you can use this in the documenttion. By the way, the last time I read the documention  (version 11, probably), the words "source" and "target" where very mysterious. First thing to realize : this has nearly nothing  to do (or maybe very loosely related) with a physical phenomenon (propagation of heat, waves...). it"s a artifice for calculus. In that context, "source" is the source of some informations that are applied at boundaries, and nothing is applied at the location of the source (It's not easy to explain without entering unter the hood:  stiffness matrix...etc...

Comment: Personnaly, I'm on the way to slowly understand this).

Comment: Funny, `0 < r < 1` in 2nd `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` of last sample seems to be necessary?

Answer (score 6):

The last geometry we can solve the problem analytically.
We set V = V0 for p from 0 to Pi/2, and V = V1 from Pi/2 to 2Pi.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pde = Laplacian[V[r, p], {r, p}, "Polar"] == 0;
```

Separate Variables

```
V[r_, p_] = R[r] P[p];

Expand[(r^2*pde)/V[r, p]]

P''[p]/P[p] + (r^2 R''[r])/R[r] + (r R'[r])/R[r] == 0
```

Each section must be equal to a constant.  We know the solution must be periodic in p so choose

```
peq = P''[p]/P[p] == -a^2;

DSolve[peq, P[p], p] // Flatten
{P[p] -> C[2]*Sin[a*p] + C[1]*Cos[a*p]}

p1 = P[p] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
```

The `r` equation becomes

```
req = -a^2 + (r^2 R''[r])/R[r] + (r R'[r])/R[r] == 0;

DSolve[req, R[r], r] // Flatten // TrigToExp;

r1 = R[r] /. % /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4}

r1 // Collect[#, r^_] &
(*(c3/2 - (I*c4)/2)/r^a + r^a*(c3/2 + (I*c4)/2)*)

r1 = % /. {c3/2 - (I*c4)/2 -> c3, c3/2 + (I*c4)/2 -> c4}
(*c3 r^-a+c4 r^a*)

Vin[r_, p_] = r1 p1
(*(c3/r^a + c4*r^a)*(c1*Cos[a*p] + c2*Sin[a*p])*)
```

`Vin` is bounded at `r = 0`, and single valued in `p`, which requires

```
c3 = 0
c4 = 1
a = n
$Assumptions = n \[Element] Integers
```

We set `c4` to 1 to combine it with `c1` and `c2`.
`Vout` is bounded at `r = Infinity` requiring

```
c8 = 0
c7 = 1
```

We end up with

```
Vin[r, p]
(*r^n (c1 Cos[n p] + c2 Sin[n p])*)

Vout[r, p]
(*r^-n (c5 Cos[n p] + c6 Sin[n p])*)
```

Work with the solution Vin for r < R
At r = R, V= V1 0 <=p <= Pi/2, and V0 otherwise
Use orthogonality to match the boundary at `r = R` and solve for the c constants.
the `n=0` term

```
eq0 = Integrate[V0, {p, 0, Pi/2}] + Integrate[V1, {p, Pi/2, 2*Pi}] == R^0*Integrate[c0, {p, 0, 2*Pi}]//FullSimplify

Solve[%, c0];

c0 = c0 /. %[[1]];
```

eq1 mult by sin and integrate

```
eq1 = Integrate[V0*Sin[n*p], {p, 0, Pi/2}] + Integrate[V1*Sin[n*p], {p, Pi/2, 2*Pi}] == 
   R^n*Integrate[(c1*Cos[n*p] + c2*Sin[n*p])*Sin[n*p], {p, 0, 2*Pi}]//FullSimplify;
```

eq2 mult by cos and integrate

```
eq2 = Integrate[V0*Cos[n*p], {p, 0, Pi/2}] + Integrate[V1*Cos[n*p], {p, Pi/2, 2*Pi}] == 
   R^n*Integrate[(c1*Cos[n*p] + c2*Sin[n*p])*Cos[n*p], {p, 0, 2*Pi}]//FullSimplify;

Solve[eq1, c2] // Flatten // FullSimplify;

c2 = c2 /. %;

Solve[eq2, c1] // Flatten // FullSimplify;

c1 = c1 /. %;
```

Put in some values

```
R = 1
V0 = 1
V1 = 0

Vin[r, p] // FullSimplify
(*(2 r^n Sin[(Pi n)/4] Cos[n (p - Pi/4)])/(Pi n)*)
```

The full solution is the c0 term plus the sum of the above over integer n.

```
c0
(*1/4*)

$Assumptions = r >= 0 && p \[Element] Reals

Vin[r_, p_] = 1/4 + (2/Pi)*Sum[(r^n*Sin[(Pi*n)/4]*Cos[n*(p - Pi/4)])/n, {n, 1, Infinity}]//FullSimplify
(*-((I*(2*Log[1 - r/E^(I*p)] - 2*Log[1 - (I*r)/E^(I*p)] - 2*Log[1 - E^(I*p)*r] + 2*Log[1 + I*E^(I*p)*r] + I*Pi))/
   (4*Pi))*)
```

MMa successfully finds a closed form solution to the infinite sum.  It looks very complex, but plotting shows that it is a real expression.

Electric field in r direction

```
Efrin[r_, p_] = -D[Vin[r, p], r] // FullSimplify
(*-((I*E^(2*I*p)*((r^2 + 1)*Sin[p] + (r^2 + 1)*Cos[p] - 2*r))/(Pi*(-r + E^(I*p))*(E^(I*p) - I*r)*(-1 + E^(I*p)*r)*
    (E^(I*p)*r - I)))*)

Plot[Efrin[R, p], {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Charge density

```
Sigma[p_] = -e0 (Efrin[R, p] // FullSimplify)
(*-(e0/(-(Pi*Sin[p]) - Pi*Cos[p] + Pi))*)
```

Surprisingly simple expression for the charge density.
Calculate the total q/length for the section opposite the potential V1.

```
q = Integrate[Sigma[p], {p, Pi, (3*Pi)/2}]

-((e0*Log[2])/Pi)

Cap = Abs[q/(V1 - V0)]
(*(e0*Log[2])/Pi*)
```

What is interesting is that the integral for Sigma over the p limits of V1 does not converge.