# Numerically solving the Laplace equation in a 2d cylinder

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Consider the following Laplace equation and boundary condition  $$\begin{equation}\begin{cases} \Delta \theta(r,\phi)=0 
\\ \int d \vec{\ell}\cdot\nabla \theta(r,\phi)=2\pi \end{cases} \end{equation}$$
where $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$, $r\in[0,\infty)$ and the integral is over a circular contour of constant $r$ around the origin such that $d\vec{\ell}=rd\phi \hat{\phi}$ with $\hat{\phi}$ a unit vector in direction $\phi$. The solution to this equation is simply $\theta(r,\phi)=\phi$.

I want to learn how to solve this equation numerically in Mathematica and (approximately) recreate the solution in Cartesian coordinates. To this end, I'm taking a cylindrical domain with an annulus to avoid problems at $r=0$. The outer radius is $R_{1}=1$ and the inner radius is $R_{0}=0.1$. 
The domain looks like this

[image]

Following [Solve Laplace equation in Cylindrical - Polar Coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174357/solve-laplace-equation-in-cylindrical-polar-coordinates), I seem to get the correct solution in polar coordinates but not in Cartesian coordinates and I don't understand why.

Any help is appreciated.

In Polar coordinates I get

[image]

and in Cartesian coordinates I get

[image]

This is the code in polar coordinates

```
R1 = 1; R0 = 0.1;
regionCyl = 
  DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionDifference[
    ImplicitRegion[
     0 <= r <= R1 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi], {r, \[Phi]}], 
    ImplicitRegion[
     0 <= r <= R0 && 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi], {r, \[Phi]}]], 
   PrecisionGoal -> 6];
laplacianCil = Laplacian[\[Theta][r, \[Phi]], {r, \[Phi]}, "Polar"];
boundaryConditionCil = {DirichletCondition[\[Theta][
      r, \[Phi]] == \[Phi], {r == R0, 0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]}], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Theta][r, \[Phi]] == \[Phi], {r == R1, 
     0 <= \[Phi] <= 2 \[Pi]}]};
solCyl = NDSolveValue[{laplacianCil == 0, 
    boundaryConditionCil}, \[Theta], {r, \[Phi]} \[Element] regionCyl,
    MaxSteps -> Infinity];
potentialSquareRepresentation = 
  ContourPlot[
   solCyl[r, \[Phi]], {r, \[Phi]} \[Element] solCyl["ElementMesh"], 
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 20, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];
potentialCylindricalRepresentation = 
 Show[potentialSquareRepresentation /. 
   GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[(#[[1]] {Cos[#[[2]]], Sin[#[[2]]]}) & /@ array1, 
     rest], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

and this is the code in Cartesian coordinates

```
R1 = 1; R0 = 0.1;
regionCyl = 
  DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionDifference[ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= R1, {x, y}], 
    ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= R0, {x, y}]], 
   PrecisionGoal -> 7];
laplacian = Laplacian[\[Theta][x, y], {x, y}];
boundaryCondition = {DirichletCondition[\[Theta][x, y] == 
     ArcSin[y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == R0, 
     0 <= y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 2 \[Pi]}], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Theta][x, y] == 
     ArcSin[y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == R1, 
     0 <= y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 2 \[Pi]}]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{laplacian == 0, 
    boundaryCondition}, \[Theta], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Comment: It's not about the solution `NDSolveValue` being incorrect (I haven't checked but it lookes plausible to me.) The problem is that the pde you gave **cannot** be interpreted as a pde on the annulus: The boundary condition forbids that. In fact, $(r,\varphi) \mapsto \varphi$ is _not_ a harmonic function on the annulus, in particular, because it must have a jump.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Then I don't understand why the solution in polar coordinates does agree with the analytical solution (in an infinite domain). How would you model this problem numerically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Cartesian coordinates, the solution $\theta $ has a gap on the line $y=0$.To get a solution, you need to make a cut and define a solution on both sides of the cut, for example:

```
R1 = 1; y0 = 0.01;
regionCyl = 
  DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionDifference[ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= R1, {x, y}], 
    ImplicitRegion[-R1 <= x <= 0 && -y0 <= y <= y0, {x, y}]]];
laplacian = Laplacian[\[Theta][x, y], {x, y}];
boundaryCondition = {DirichletCondition[\[Theta][x, y] == 
     ArcTan[x, y], x^2 + y^2 == R1^2], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Theta][x, y] == Pi, y == y0], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Theta][x, y] == -Pi, y == -y0]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{laplacian == 0, 
    boundaryCondition}, \[Theta], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {\[Theta] -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}];


{DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Medium], 
 ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regionCyl, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, Contours -> 20]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: I see your point. Thanks @Alex Trounev

Comment: @AsafMiron You're welcome!

Comment: just wondering, is it straightforward to generalize this solution if instead of the Laplace equation theta I have two coupled nonlinear PDE for theta and another field?

Comment: Does this other field depend on theta and also have a gap?

Comment: Both fields are coupled by non-linear equations and depend on both x and y. I'm interested in boundary conditions that, similarly to my original post, are equal to $\phi$ along a circle centered around $x=x_{0},y=0$ and $-\phi$ along a circle centered around $x=-x_{0},y=0$. Thus, there is a gap along the interval $[-x_{0},x_{0}]$. Both circles have radius $R_{0}$ which is much smaller than $R_{1}$, the large outer circle radius.

Comment: If the equations are non-linear, we will not be able to directly use FEM.  We'll have to start a new topic with this problem.

Comment: Sure thing, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191787/numerically-solving-2-coupled-nonlinear-pdes. Thank you so much for willing to help.