# FEM: Solving the heat conduction with 2D periodic condition

Tags: finite-element-method, periodic-function

Suppose you have a region $\Omega = [0,P_1] \times [0,P_2]$ which is composed of, e.g., two materials. One material is distributed as inclusions in an embedding  material. We split the region as $\Omega = \Omega_{inc} \cup \Omega_{emb}$ (inclusion and embedding material). Example for $P = (10,5)$ with 3 inclusions:

```
(*Periodic region with periods P*)
P = {10, 5};
Omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, P];
centers = {{1.2, 2}, {6, 3}, {8.5, 1.5}};
Omegainc = RegionUnion[Disk[#, 1] & /@ centers];
Omegaemb = RegionDifference[Omega, Omegainc];
RegionPlot[{Omegainc, Omegaemb}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\[CapitalOmega]inc", "\[CapitalOmega]emb"}]
```

[image]

How would you solve the following periodic 2-dimensional heat conduction problem for the unkonwn temperature $u(x) = u(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}$ and periodic $v(x) \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\mathrm{div}(A(x) \mathrm{grad}(u(x))) = 0 \quad x \in \Omega
, \quad
u(x) = g^T x + v(x) \quad x \in \partial \Omega
\ ,
$$
$$
A(x) = 
\begin{cases}
A_{inc} & x \in \Omega_{inc} \\
A_{emb} & x \in \Omega_{emb} 
\end{cases}
$$
The constant vector $g \in \mathbb{R}^2$ in the boundary conditions ($g^Tx = g_1 x_1 + g_2 x_2$) as well as the conductivities $A_{inc},A_{emb} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ are given, the unknown periodic field $v(x)$ is to be determined (periodicity for $v(x)$: $v(x_1,0) = v(x_1,P_2) \ \forall x_1 \in [0,P_1]$ and $v(0,x_2) = v(P_1,x2) \ \forall x_2 \in [0,P_2]$). For complete clarity, the homogeneous PDE above can also be expressed as
$$
\sum_{p=1}^2 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_p}
\left( 
\sum_{q=1}^2 A_{pq}(x)
\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_q}
\right)
= 0
\quad x \in \Omega
$$
**How would you solve the problem above with the FEM in Mathematica?**

---

**My approach until now:** I split the solution directly into $u(x) = g^T x + v(x)$, insert it into the PDE and solve for the periodic $v(x)$, i.e., solve the **inhomogeneous** PDE
$$
\mathrm{div}(A(x)g) + \mathrm{div}(A(x)\mathrm{grad}(v(x))]) = 0
$$
with corresponding periodic boundary conditions for $v(x)$. Hereby, I am not very sure if simply inserting this into the FEM with `Inactivate` is actually fine for the inhomogeneity $\mathrm{div}(A(x)g)$. How does Mathematica treat this inhomogeneity, does it take advantage of the inactive divergence? Based on the code given above for the region generation, my solution code is given below:

1. Mesh generation
2. Region dependent coefficient $A(x)$
3. Boundary conditions (1 Dirichlet and periodic)
4. PDE with prescribed $g$
5. Solve on mesh
6. Check periodicity along edges and visualize solution (seem fine to me)

**Minor question:** In step 5. Solve on mesh I get the error that $A(x)$ can not be transposed. What am I doing wrong there?

[image]

Thanks!

```
(*Mesh*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   Omegaemb
   , "RegionHoles" -> None
   , "RegionMarker" -> 
    Join[{#, 1, 0.05} & /@ centers, {{{0.1, 0.1}, 2, 0.5}}]
   ];
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ {Blue, Orange}]]

(*Region dependent coefficient A(x)*)
Ainc = DiagonalMatrix@{100, 50};
Aemb = DiagonalMatrix@{1, 2};
A[x1_, x2_] := If[Element[{x1, x2}, Omegainc], Ainc, Aemb];

(*Region dependent coefficient A(x)*)
Ainc = DiagonalMatrix@{100, 50};
Aemb = DiagonalMatrix@{1, 2};
A[x1_, x2_] := If[Element[{x1, x2}, Omegainc], Ainc, Aemb];

(*Boundary conditions*)
bcD = DirichletCondition[v[x1, x2] == 0, x1 == 0 && x2 == 0];
gt1 = FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {0, P[[2]]}}, {{P[[1]], 0}, 
     P}][[2]];
gt2 = FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {P[[1]], 0}}, {{0, P[[2]]}, 
     P}][[2]];
bcP = {
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
    v[x1, x2]
    , x1 == P[[1]] && 0 <= x2 <= P[[2]]
    , gt1
    ]
   ,
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
    v[x1, x2]
    , x2 == P[[2]] && 0 <= x1 <= P[[1]]
    , gt2
    ]
   };

(*PDE with prescribed g*)
g = {3, 1};
pde = Inactive[Div][A[x1, x2].g, {x1, x2}] + 
    Inactive[Div][
     A[x1, x2].Inactive[Grad][v[x1, x2], {x1, x2}], {x1, x2}] == 0;

(*Solve on mesh*)
vsol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bcD, bcP}, v, Element[{x1, x2}, mesh]];

(*Check periodictiy along edges and visualize solution*)
Plot[
 vsol[x1, 0] - vsol[x1, P[[2]]], {x1, 0, P[[1]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"v[x1,0]-v[x1,P2]"}]
Plot[vsol[0, x2] - vsol[P[[1]], x2], {x2, 0, P[[2]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"v[0,x2]-v[P1,x2]"}]
Show[ContourPlot[vsol[x1, x2], Element[{x1, x2}, Omega], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 RegionPlot@Omegainc]
Plot3D[vsol[x1, x2], Element[{x1, x2}, Omega]]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I only want $v(x)$ to be periodic throughout the boundary. That is sufficient for the uniqueness of the solution (up to a constant, of course), as far as I remember, I do not need to specify anything for the flux.

Comment: You use an undifferentiable function as differentiable in `Inactive[Div][A[x1, x2].g, {x1, x2}]`. Therefore, we have a message. But FEM it is not BEM. You have to use `NeumannValue[]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev that is not a problem. For such PDEs, you can also use, e.g., linear elements such that $A(x) \mathrm{grad}(v(x))$ would not be differentiable when passing it to $\mathrm{div}$. Using the weak formulation and integration by parts allows to get rid of the divergence operation. This should also not be a problem for the term $A(x)g$. I just found out that this case fits the term $\gamma$ in the general PDE in the [FEM documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601). But I still dont get it, why I get an error there.

Comment: Then see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/212208/18437) question and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212240/18437) answer also applies here.

When you use

```
(*PDE with prescribed g*)
g = {{3}, {1}};
```

Things then work as expected. The Inactive Div then does the differentiation. It's worthwhile noting that the numerical differentiation is probably less accurate then if you have a symbolic derivative.

Note the other improvements in that post also apply here.

For completeness the plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I also realized after some digging that the $\gamma$ term was the issue and decided to ask a question specifically for it in a non-periodic setting.

Comment: @user21  it looks like a solution, but what describes this solution and how to find out what is right?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, $\gamma$ is used for computing derivatives (divergences) of functions. This sometime is convenient to do in the FEM code, as in this case. How to check if this is correct, well like in any other case you construct an example for which you have an analytical solution:

Comment: `Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
test = Sin[x];
nr = ToNumericalRegion[Line[{{0}, {2 \[Pi]}}]];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u}, {x}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData["Space" -> nr];
pdec = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
   "ReactionCoefficients" -> {{1}},
   "LoadDerivativeCoefficients" -> {{{-test}}}]; mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[pdec, mdata, sd];
{l, s, d, m} = dpde["All"];
res = LinearSolve[s, l];
if = ElementMeshInterpolation[{nr["ElementMesh"]}, res];
Plot[Evaluate[if[x] - D[test, x]], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: @user21 I asked not at all, but in this particular case. At first glance, my solution describes the same thing, but the result is completely different.

Comment: @user21 one last question regarding periodicity: I just noticed that `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` helps to ensure periodic continuity of the solution in my problem. But over the corresponding edges, physical balance is violated. By that I mean that, e.g., the flux on the left edge at any point does NOT balance out with the flux at the right edge at the corresponding periodic point. From a physical point of view, this is critical. I was trying to also read into `NeumannValue` but I could not find an option in order to impose that. Do you know what I mean? If yes, how would you do that?

Comment: @MauricioFernández, have a look at the update in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174514/18437) answer - this might be a solution for your problem too.

Answer (score 4):

We have to use either `NeumannValue[]` or save the linear function in the `pde` as follows

```
(*Mesh*)Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(*Periodic region with periods P*)

P = {10, 5};
Omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, P];
centers = {{1.2, 2}, {6, 3}, {8.5, 1.5}};
Omegainc = RegionUnion[Disk[#, 1] & /@ centers];
Omegaemb = RegionDifference[Omega, Omegainc];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Omegaemb, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> 
    Join[{#, 1, 0.05} & /@ centers, {{{0.1, 0.1}, 2, 0.5}}]];
{RegionPlot[{Omegainc, Omegaemb}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> {"\[CapitalOmega]inc", "\[CapitalOmega]emb"}], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ {Blue, Orange}]]}

(*Region dependent coefficient A(x)*)
Ainc = DiagonalMatrix@{100, 50};
Aemb = DiagonalMatrix@{1, 2};
A[x1_, x2_] := Boole[Element[{x1, x2}, Omegainc]] (Ainc - Aemb) + Aemb;

(*Boundary conditions*)eps = 10^-3;
bcD = DirichletCondition[v[x1, x2] == RandomReal[{-eps, eps}], 
   x1 == 0 && x2 == 0];
gt1 = FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {0, P[[2]]}}, {{P[[1]], 0}, 
     P}][[2]];
gt2 = FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {P[[1]], 0}}, {{0, P[[2]]}, 
     P}][[2]];
bcP = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x1, x2], 
    x1 == P[[1]] && 0 <= x2 <= P[[2]], gt1], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x1, x2], 
    x2 == P[[2]] && 0 <= x1 <= P[[1]], gt2]};

(*PDE with prescribed g*)
g = 3 x1 + x2;
pde = Inactive[Div][
     A[x1, x2].Inactive[Grad][v[x1, x2], {x1, x2}], {x1, x2}] + 
    Inactive[Div][A[x1, x2].Inactive[Grad][g, {x1, x2}], {x1, x2}] == 
   0;

(*Solve on mesh*)
vsol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bcP, bcD}, v, Element[{x1, x2}, mesh]]
(*Check periodictiy along edges and visualize solution*)
{Plot[vsol[x1, 0] - vsol[x1, P[[2]]], {x1, 0, P[[1]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-eps, eps}, PlotLegends -> {"v[x1,0]-v[x1,P2]"}],
 Plot[vsol[0, x2] - vsol[P[[1]], x2], {x2, 0, P[[2]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-eps, eps}, PlotLegends -> {"v[0,x2]-v[P1,x2]"}],
 Show[ContourPlot[vsol[x1, x2], Element[{x1, x2}, Omega], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
  RegionPlot@Omegainc]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: That does not make sense to me. The solution you get is a constant throughout the region, equal to the random value between -eps and +eps you initialized the Dirichlet condition at $(x_1,x_2) = (0,0)$. See your plot. You can put 0.3 as the Dirichlet condition and the returned solution will be 0.3 throughout the region. That seems not right.

Comment: What solution do you want using `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[]`?

Comment: I expect the solution $v(x)$ to do weird stuff inside the region due to the 2 different materials and to be periodic (see, e.g., the solution plot at the bottom of my question). That is all. A constant $v(x)$ trivially vanishes in the gradient such that $A(x) \mathrm{grad}(v(x))$ would vanish overall. That does not seem right to me.

Comment: You use a linear function that is not periodic. What do you want to get?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. The periodic function $v(x)$ is the one I want to get. The inhomogeneity vector $A(x)g$ in the PDE can be considered as periodic (periodic matrix fiel $A(x)$ and constant vector $g$), so there is no vialotation of periodicity for the problem.

Comment: No, you are wrong, because the system found an error in your `pde`. On the other hand, there are no errors in my `pde`. And you see what happened. Try to formulate the problem as it is. What do you want to describe using this code?

Comment: That was not the issue. The issue was the Mathematica evaluation of the term $\gamma(x) = A(x)g$, see user21's answer and my addition question he points at.