# Cylindrical coordinates in FEM

Tags: finite-element-method, coordinate-transformation, fluid-dynamics, opencascade

I am trying to solve the Stokes equation for fluid flow in a 3d cylinder. All boundaries are no-slip, apart from the top boundary, which enforces flow in the x-direction.

My problem is that I can't enforce periodic boundary conditions at -pi and pi in the azimuthal direction for the pressure. Instead of a solution, I get the errors:

NDSolve: DirichletCondition can not be present on the target boundary of a PeriodicBoundaryConditon.
NDSolve: The boundary condition discretization failed.

When I omit the periodic pressure condition, NDSolve finishes, but the solution has a problem around the origin. Also the flows should be mirror-symmetric across the x-axis due to the top boundary condition, but they are not as can be seen in the x-component of the flow field.

[image]

I already incorporated the trick of extending the domain in azimuthal direction from here: [Solve Laplace equation in Cylindrical - Polar Coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174357/solve-laplace-equation-in-cylindrical-polar-coordinates). But that did not seem to help.

What can I do to get a good solution out of NDSolve?

Below is a minimal working example.

```
(** PDE **)
cs = "Cylindrical";
stokesEqns = {
   Simplify[
      Laplacian[{ur[r, \[Phi], z], u\[Phi][r, \[Phi], z], 
        uz[r, \[Phi], z]}, {r, \[Phi], z}, cs]] - 
     Simplify[Grad[pp[r, \[Phi], z], {r, \[Phi], z}, cs]] == {0, 0, 0},
   Simplify[
     Div[{ur[r, \[Phi], z], u\[Phi][r, \[Phi], z], 
       uz[r, \[Phi], z]}, {r, \[Phi], z}, cs]] == 0
   };

(** boundary conditions **)
{u0r, u0\[Phi], u0z} = 
  TransformedField[
    "Cartesian" -> cs, {1, 0, 0}, {xx, yy, zz} -> {r, \[Phi], z}] /. 
   z -> 1;
boundaryConditions = {
   DirichletCondition[{ur[r, \[Phi], z] == u0r, 
     u\[Phi][r, \[Phi], z] == u0\[Phi], uz[r, \[Phi], z] == u0z}, 
    z == 1 \[And] -\[Pi] < \[Phi] < \[Pi]],
   DirichletCondition[{ur[r, \[Phi], z] == 0, 
     u\[Phi][r, \[Phi], z] == 0, uz[r, \[Phi], z] == 0, 
     pp[r, \[Phi], z] == 0}, z == -1 \[And] -\[Pi] < \[Phi] < \[Pi]],
   DirichletCondition[{ur[r, \[Phi], z] == 0, 
     u\[Phi][r, \[Phi], z] == 0, uz[r, \[Phi], z] == 0, 
     pp[r, \[Phi], z] == 0}, r == 1 \[And] -\[Pi] < \[Phi] < \[Pi]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ur[r, \[Phi], z], \[Phi] == -\[Pi], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2 \[Pi], 0}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u\[Phi][r, \[Phi], z], \[Phi] == -\[Pi], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2 \[Pi], 0}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[uz[r, \[Phi], z], \[Phi] == -\[Pi], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2 \[Pi], 0}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[pp[r, \[Phi], z], \[Phi] == -\[Pi], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2 \[Pi], 0}]]
   };

(** solve **)
AbsoluteTiming[
  solFEM = 
    NDSolve[{stokesEqns, boundaryConditions}, {ur, u\[Phi], uz, 
       pp}, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi] + \[Pi]/4}, {z, -1, 1}, 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "InterpolationOrder" -> {ur -> 2, u\[Phi] -> 2, uz -> 2, 
          pp -> 1}}][[1]];
  ][[1]]


(** plot **)
field[xx_, yy_, zz_] = 
  TransformedField[
   cs -> "Cartesian", {ur[r, \[Phi], z], u\[Phi][r, \[Phi], z], 
     uz[r, \[Phi], z]} /. solFEM, {r, \[Phi], z} -> {xx, yy, zz}];
ppCart[xx_, yy_, zz_] = 
  TransformedField[cs -> "Cartesian", 
   pp[r, \[Phi], z] /. solFEM, {r, \[Phi], z} -> {xx, yy, zz}];
DensityPlot3D[
 field[x, y, z][[1]]
 , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}
 , PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "x-component of flow"]
```

Comment: Seen that you transform back to Cartesian coordinates why not just solve the problem in Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: The issue with `DirichletCondition` present at the target can be very subtle. Make sure that the specification for the `DirichletCondition` predicate and the target do not overlap at any point. Initially try to reduce the position of the `DirichletCondition` as much as possible (even to a smaller space then what you finally want) and then to get the PBCs working then enlarge to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a lid driven flow problem.  I am in agreement with @user21's perspective that you should solve this in Cartesian Coordinates.  It should simplify the boundary condition specification.  Since the system is closed, you will need to define pressure at a node.  I used OpenCascade to build the half cylinder.  Here is the workflow.

```
(* Load Required Packages *)
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Use OpenCascade To Make Half Sym Geometry *)
pp = Polygon[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}}];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[pp];
axis = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, axis, -Pi];
(* Create Mesh *)
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .075}, 
   "IncludePoints" -> {{0, 0.5, -1}}];
groups = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
(* Create PDE System *)
ClearAll[μ]
op = {Inactive[
              Div][({{-μ, 0, 0}, {0, -μ, 0}, {0, 
                    0, -μ}}.Inactive[Grad][
         u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]), {x, y, 
              z}] + 
     D[p[x, y, z], x], 
        Inactive[
              Div][({{-μ, 0, 0}, {0, -μ, 0}, {0, 
                    0, -μ}}.Inactive[Grad][
         v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]), {x, y, 
              z}] + 
     D[p[x, y, z], y],
        Inactive[
              Div][({{-μ, 0, 0}, {0, -μ, 0}, {0, 
                    0, -μ}}.Inactive[Grad][
         w[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]), {x, y, 
              z}] + 
     D[p[x, y, z], z], 
    D[u[x, y, z], x] + 
     D[v[x, y, z], y] + 
     D[w[x, y, z], z]} /. μ -> 1;
pde = op == {0, 0, 0, 0};
bcs = {DirichletCondition[
        {u[x, y, z] == 1, v[x, y, z] == 0., w[x, y, z] == 0.}, 
    z == 1.],
      DirichletCondition[
        {u[x, y, z] == 0, v[x, y, z] == 0., w[x, y, z] == 0.}, 
        z == -1. || (x^2 + y^2) > 0.99], 
      DirichletCondition[v[x, y, z] == 0., y > -0.001],
      DirichletCondition[p[x, y, z] == 0., 
        x == 0. && z == -1.](*pressure Point Condition*)};
(* Solve PDE *)
{xVel, yVel, zVel, pressure} = 
    NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs}, {u, v, w, p}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 2, p -> 1}}];
(* Visualize Solution *)
surf = {{"YStackedPlanes", {0}}, {"ZStackedPlanes", {-1, 1}}};
Show[SliceContourPlot3D[
    Norm@{xVel[x, y, z], yVel[x, y, z], zVel[x, y, z]}, 
    surf, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    BoxRatios -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], 
  ImageSize -> Medium, ViewPoint -> Front]
DensityPlot3D[
  Norm[{xVel[x, y, z], yVel[x, y, z], zVel[x, y, z]}], {x, y, 
      z} ∈ mesh, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ViewAngle -> 0.3669386546105606`,
  ViewPoint -> {3.7435513617679828`, 1.2106476957796874`, 
   0.9258298223054351`}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0.27079048490259205`, 0.14735018657087556`, 
   0.9512940848148628`}]
SliceVectorPlot3D[{xVel[x, y, z], yVel[x, y, z], 
    zVel[x, y, z]}, surf, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
 VectorPoints -> 20,
   VectorColorFunction -> "BrightBands", BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image: Mesh and Solution Plots]

Qualitatively, it agrees with the COMSOL model I threw together.

[image: COMSOL Solution]

Comment: This is awesome! Could you clarify two points? 1) For the pressure point condition you specfiy x and z-coordinates, but not y. I added it in and it does not seem to change anything. Is it implicitly set to y=0? 2) This is basically a test problem I wanted to understand before continuing with a more complicated two-phase flow problem in spherical coordinates. What I take away from your answer is that with FEM I should stay in cartesian coordinates, b/c curvilinear coordinates introduce messy artifacts. Is that right?

Comment: @Oscillon 1) Picking a node with conditional statement is not necessarily a robust way to pick a pressure point, because there is no guarantee the mesher will put a point there.  I chose the bottom of the tank because the flow is relatively static (very small pressure gradients), so there is a chance multiple points were grabbed, but had little effect.  A more robust approach would be to explicitly define the pressure point in `ToElementMesh` .  2) I would only use curvilinear coordinates if I could take advantage of symmetry and reduce the dimension of the problem I am solving. Continued-

Comment: @Oscillon If the dimension stays the same, you may as well let the mesher do the heavy lifting of meshing the shape you want to model.  Regarding two-phase flow, I hope that you have a defined fluid-fluid interface.  Implementing free surfaces in FEM codes is not trivial and the solutions are expensive.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version in Cartesian coordinates to get you started:

```
reg = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1];

a = IdentityMatrix[3];
stokesFlowOperator = {Inactive[Div][
     a.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] - 
    D[p[x, y, z], x], 
   Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] -
     D[p[x, y, z], y], 
   Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][w[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] -
     D[p[x, y, z], z], 
   Div[{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]};
\[CapitalGamma]D = {
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 1., v[x, y, z] == 0., 
     w[x, y, z] == 0.}, x == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0., v[x, y, z] == 0., 
     w[x, y, z] == 0.}, x < 1], 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y, z] == 0, x == -1 && y == 0 && z == 1]};

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];

{xVel, yVel, zVel, pressure} = 
  NDSolveValue[{stokesFlowOperator == {0, 0, 0, 
      0}, \[CapitalGamma]D}, {u, v, w, p}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 2, p -> 1}}];
```

You'd need to think more about the boundary conditions, especially the pressure condition.

```
rmf = RegionMember[MeshRegion[mesh]];
Quiet[VectorPlot3D[{xVel[x, y, z], yVel[x, y, z], zVel[x, y, z]}, 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Join[{{x}, {y}, {z}}, mesh["Bounds"]*1.01, 2]],
   VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  VectorScale -> {Tiny, Scaled[0.4], None}, VectorPoints -> {9, 9, 9},
   Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
  RegionFunction -> (rmf[{#1, #2, #3}] &)], 
 InterpolatingFunction::femdmval]
```

[image]