NDSolve the 1D Poisson Equation on a Periodic Domain
I want to use NDSolve on the simple equation
$$ q'' == g(q,h) $$ for some function $g$ on the domain $ \Omega=[-1,1]$
with periodic boundary conditions $$ q(-1)=q(1) \text{ and } q'(-1) = q'(1)$$
using finite elements. I set
c=Simplify[(1/10)^2 D[-1+E^(-4+3 Cos[\[Pi] (1/2+x)])-q[x],{x,2}]+ q[x]]

for the equation and try
dsol=NDSolve[{
    c==NeumannValue[a,x==1]+NeumannValue[-a,x==-1],
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[q[x],x==1 || x==-1,-#&]},
    {q,a},{x,-1,1},
    Method->{"FiniteElement"}];

The result is a function $q$ that is close to the correct solution and
$q(-1)=q(1)$ holds, but the derivative on the boundary is not correct. What am I doing wrong here?

Value of parameter a is undefined.

I tried here to make sure the derivatives at the boundary coincide by setting them equal to the same (undefined) parameter.

If you try NDSolveValue[{q[x] +      1/100 (3 E^(-4 - 3 Sin[\[Pi] x]) \[Pi]^2 (3 Cos[\[Pi] x]^2 +            Sin[\[Pi] x]) - q''[x]) == 0, q[1] == q[-1],    q'[1] == q'[-1] }, q, {x, -1, 1}  ] without "FiniteElement" Mathematica gives an error message "boundary conditions are numerically ill-conditioned"

You might try to solve the problem analytically

I know there are other options but I am curious if finite elements would work

At this time, the periodic boundary condition on the derivative q'(-1)=q'(1) is not implemented in Mathematica.
Here is a trick to impose it :
c = Simplify[(1/10)^2 D[-1 + E^(-4 + 3 Cos[\[Pi] (1/2 + x)]) - 
  q[x], {x, 2}] + q[x]]

a = 1
dsol = NDSolveValue[{q[x] + 
      1/100 (3 E^(-4 - 3 Sin[\[Pi] x]) \[Pi]^2 (3 Cos[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
            Sin[\[Pi] x]) - q''[x]) == 0, 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[q[x], x == 1.5, 
     TranslationTransform[{-2}]], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[q[x], x == -1, 
     TranslationTransform[{2}]]}, q, {x, -1, 1.5}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];

Plot[dsol[x], {x, -1, 1}]


The domain is extended to [-1,1.5] and the required periodicity is
on [-1,1], as you can see on the graphics.
Some elements of explanation : why are derivatives periodic ?
Here is a plot of the solution over the domain [-1,1.5] :

The Dirichlet boundary condition PeriodicBoundaryCondition[q[x], x == 1.5, TranslationTransform[{-2}]] imposes dsol[pt4] == dsol[pt2]
The Dirichlet boundary condition PeriodicBoundaryCondition[q[x],x == -1,TranslationTransform[{2}]] imposes dsol[pt1] == dsol[pt3]
Now why are segments [pt1,pt2] and [pt3,pt4] identical ?
Because the solution of a differential equation of order 2 is uniquely determined by the :

two boundaries of the domain
the source term of the Poisson equation, which is periodic too.

Idem for two identical segments [pt2,pt3] (they are superposed on the graphic)
So, finally the derivative at pt1-right and pt3-right are identical because segments are identical.
Last problem : why the derivatives at pt1-right and pt3-left are the same : because pt3 in inside the segment [pt2-pt4] where the poisson equation is fully respected (=> right derivative == left derivative).
I hope it's understantable! but I'm not sure !

This problem is not new (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204546/5467)

Nice solution (+1). Your solution idea is known in the Mathemetica community as " ghost layer && PeriodicBoundaryCondition". Try eps = 0.00001; dsol = NDSolveValue[{q[x] +        1/100 (3 E^(-4 - 3 Sin[\[Pi] x]) \[Pi]^2 (3 Cos[\[Pi] x]^2 +              Sin[\[Pi] x]) - q''[x]) == 0,      PeriodicBoundaryCondition[q[x], x == 1 + eps,       TranslationTransform[{-2}]],      PeriodicBoundaryCondition[q[x], x == -1,       TranslationTransform[{2}]]}, q, {x, -1, 1 + eps},     Method -> {"FiniteElement"}]; 

@UlrichNeumann  (!)  I'm probably the inventor of this solution, on MSE, a long time ago, without giving it a name.

I have done this too : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174514/5467

It was not my intention to doubt the authorship, I just wanted to give two helpful keywords for the further search

No problem. In fact I have answered the question above because it is not polluted by problems other than the main point : How to implement periodicity on the derivative too ?. All others question needs to solve a lot of accessories problems.

Thank you very much for this helpful and clear answer!

I don't know why "FiniteElement" method fails without andre314`s trick.
If we apply Galerkinmethod   we get the correct numerical FEMsolution without problems
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];

discretization
    xi = Subdivide[-1, 1, 100];
xwGauss = 
   Flatten[
   Map[GaussianQuadratureWeights[3(*5*), #[[1]], #[[2]]] & , 
    Partition[xi, 2, 1]], 1] ;

netz = ToElementMesh[Map[{#} &, xi]];
phi = Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[netz, #] &, 
   IdentityMatrix[Length[xi]]];
\[Phi]i = Function[x, Evaluate[Through[phi[x]]]];
\[Phi]is = Function[x, Evaluate@D[Through[phi[x]], x]];

qi = Table[q[i], {i, Length[xi]}];

Galerkin method
    M0 = 100 Total@
    Map[#[[2]] Outer[Times, \[Phi]i[#[[1]]] , \[Phi]i[#[[1]]] ] &, 
     xwGauss];
M1 = Total@
   Map[#[[2]] Outer[Times, \[Phi]i[#[[1]]] , \[Phi]is[#[[1]]] ] &, 
    xwGauss];
rS = Total@
   Map[#[[2]] 3 E^(-4 - 
         3 Sin[\[Pi] #[[1]]]) \[Pi]^2 (3 Cos[\[Pi] #[[1]]]^2 + 
        Sin[\[Pi] #[[1]]])  \[Phi]i[#[[1]]] &, xwGauss];

systemequations
    eqn = M1 . qi + M0 . qi + 
   rS - ( \[Phi]is[1] . qi ) + ( \[Phi]is[-1] . qi ) ;
bc = { \[Phi]i[1] . qi - \[Phi]i[-1] . qi,  \[Phi]is[1] . 
    qi  - \[Phi]is[-1] . qi };(*//Rationalize[#,0]&*)

solution
mini = NMinimize[# . # &[Join[eqn[[2 ;; -2]], bc]], qi];
Transpose[{xi, qi /. mini[[2]]}] // 
 ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All] &


Hope it helps
